# Estimate the effect of a buy order on stock price

Tags: order-execution

If a stock is having ask = 100$ for 100 shares Ask size, and I put a buy market order for 1000 shares, is there an approach to estimate that this buy order will move up the stock price by what %?

I am looking for a general approach as I understand that the question may not have a definite answer. Let us assume no iceberg orders or dark pools.

Comment: Research "market impact".